# dotnet new project can't restore it's dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I wanted to create a web app using mvc6 and searched for *ASP.NET 5 preview templates* in *ASP.NET web application(.Net Framework)* i couldn't find it and i searched further more in google. Most of the solutions said to install *ASP.NET Core*  to get the preview templates and somehow i got it by installing the *ASP.NET Core*. I was creating a new project as below.

[image]

[image]

After this step it is creating the new project for me, but then these things are happening to my new project.

[image]

To all the dependencies that i have in my project are getting the similar error like this:

> `NU1002   The dependency System.Runtime.Handles 4.0.1 does not support`
>   `framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.`

here is my  project.json

```
project.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
```

and this is my nuget.config(*C:\Users\Charitha\AppData\Roaming\NuGet*):

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
   <add key="dotnet.cli" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-cli/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="dotnet.core" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="RC2" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="AspNetCI" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcirelease/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

> I have aleady installed
>
> - .NET Core Tools for Visual Studio
> - DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to also install the .NET Core SDK if you haven't already: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core

Comment: Thanks for the respond and yes i have installed the SDK also, If um not wrong it was around 42mbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are pointing to released versions of packages, your `NuGet.Config` should just look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

If you do *not* want to change the Nuget.config file content globally, then you can create a NuGet.Config file local to the application and make sure to add a `<clear />` as the first element under the `<packageSources>` node so that you discard any inherited sources.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling lot of times i found an answer. Um not quite sure of the this but  what i did was just replaced the project.json file with the following code.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

"tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
"version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
"imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
}
},

"frameworks": {

"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    }
  },
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
},
"net461": {
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
},

"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"runtimeOptions": {
"gcServer": true
},

"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "web.config"
  ]
},

"scripts": {
"prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
}
}
```

this might help for someone.